# Spinner in dialog has no options

Tags: android, dialog

I've created a `DialogFragment` with a custom layout. This layout has a `AppCompactSpinner` which needs to be populated with 4 options. Here's the code of the fragment:

class ReportDialog : DialogFragment() {

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return activity?.let {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
        builder.setView(R.layout.fragment_report_dialog)
        builder.create()
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null!")
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    view.reportSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(
        requireContext(),
        R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item,
        arrayOf(
            "Option1",
            "Option2",
            "Option3",
            "Option4"
        )
    )
    view.reportSpinner.setSelection(0)
}
```

}
I use this fragment inside my activity to show the dialog on a button click. Everything works fine except the spinner is empty with no options. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onViewCreated is never called so you need to put your spinner adapter creation logic inside of onCreateDialog like that:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return requireContext().let {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
        builder.setView(getDialogSpinner())
        builder.create()
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null!")
}

private fun getDialogSpinner(): View {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, null)
    view.coolSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(
        requireContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        arrayOf(
            "Option1",
            "Option2",
            "Option3",
            "Option4"
        )
    )
    view.coolSpinner.setSelection(0)
    return view
}
```